# C# method accepting a predicate - does this look ok?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, func, predicates

I'd like a method that has the following API:

```
//get all users with a role of admin
var users = myRepository.GetUsers(u => u.Role == Role.Admin);
```

Will something like this work?

```
IList<User> GetUsers(Func<User, bool> predicate)
{            
  var users = GetAllUsers();
  return users.Where(predicate).ToList();                                                          
}
```

If so, wil I be able to specify more complex predicates such as (**pseudocode**):

```
myRepository.GetUsers(u => u.CreatedDate is upto 14 days old);
```

Comment: Why don't you want to return an IEnumerable of users?

Comment: Is an IEnumerable preferable because it is more flexible?

Comment: An IList is an IEnumerable, so an IEnumerable is going to be less flexible.  I think the comment may have been directed toward the possible unneeded call to ToList()?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That looks absolutely fine. However, if you want to use the predicate with something like LINQ to SQL, you'd want to use:

```
IList<User> GetUsers(Expression<Func<User, bool>> predicate)
```

That means the lambda expression will be converted into an expression tree instead of a delegate - and that expression tree can then be converted into SQL.

Comment: Really appreciate your response. Thanks

Comment: +1 That explanation clarified my understanding of LINQ by a couple percent. Much obliged. :)

Comment: Thanks much for this answer. I'm using LINQ to SQL, and using just Func<User,bool> throws an OutOfMemory exception. This works perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this will work.

What you're telling the compiler is that you're going to pass a function that works on a `User` object, and returns a `bool` - what the function looks like is entirely up to you. You can get pretty complex nesting stuff using ors (`||`) and ands (`&&`) too, but if it gets too hard to see what the predicate is doing, you should probably consider refactoring.

But basically any lambda that takes for example `u` as a `User` object, and turns it into an expression that returns `bool` will work.

Answer (score 2):

One tip: you can use Predicate<T> instead of Func<T, bool>, which is a little clearer (Predicate<T> is built in to .net 3.5, namespace System).

Comment: `Predicate<T>` was actually in .NET 2.0, but `Func<T,bool>` tends to be used in LINQ - partly because some methods have `Func<T,int,bool>`.

Comment: Ah I forgot that it was in 2.0; could you give me a few examples of methods using Func<T, int, bool>? Thanks